# t00j flashing unlock unknown command

Tags: bootloader, bootloader-lock, asus-zenfone-5

I have been trying to unlock my devices(zefnone 5 t00j) bootloader, when i type `fastboot oem unlock` i get

`FAILED (remote: 'unknown OEM command')`

`fastboot: error: Command failed`

on the cmd, and when i type `fastboot flashing unlock` i do not get anything on the cmd, but i get `"RESULT: FAIL(unkown command) on my phone.`

please help.

Comment: Your device [Asus Zenfone 5 A500CG (2014)](https://www.gsmarena.com/asus_zenfone_5_a500cg_(2014)-5952.php) seem to use an Intel CPU. Therefore it belongs to a very rare device category. Therefore everything you read about Android devices can be totally different on your device. `fastboot oem` commands are not standardized, every manufacturer can implement what they want. Therefore you need a tutorial exactly for your device, try e.g. https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/root-asus-zenfone-5-kitkat-4-4-2-100-work.2947092/

Comment: does not work im afraid, still thanks for the reply though